# Parsing JSONArray when no key is present using restassured

Tags: json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

i am using restassured to test my rest APIs and I have a scenario where my rest API returns a JSONArray without any key value like below. While browsing through multiple questions i havent seen similar JSONArray handled without key value. Verifying such a JSON is supported by RestAssured ?

[
    "Test_1 Bundle_01",
     "Test_2 Bundle_02",
     "Test_3 Bundle_03"
    ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do this by using jsonpath.

```
List<String> newlist = JsonPath.with(response.asInputStream()).get("$");
System.out.println(newlist.get(0).toString());
```

By using jsonpath and storing the response in a list of string, individual string can be accessed easily.